# How to combine objects with the same elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to combine same key element in below object and new array as output.

```
    const items = [
    {status:'all',task:'AA'},
    {status:'all',task:'BB'},
    {status:'working',task:'XX'},
    {status:'working',task:'YY'},
    {status:'complete',task:'ZZ'},
]
```

In items, I want to combine same status and make new array like below.

```
    const newItems = [
    {status:'all',task:['AA','BB']},
    {status:'working',task:['XX','YY']},
    {status:'complete',task:['ZZ']},
]
```

So I tried to make code below.

```
    let baseItems = items
const newItems = baseItems.map((e)=>{
    const newBaseItems = baseItems.filter((v)=>v.status === e.status)
    newBaseItems.map((e)=>{
        return {
            status:e.status,
            task:e.task
        }
    })        
})
console.log(newItems)
```

but out was like [undefined,undefined,,,,]
Does anyone teach me, please?

Comment: At the very least you'll need to return `newBaseItems` in the first map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a nested loop is the right approach here. Iterate *just once*, into an object indexed by `status`. On each iteration, create a `{ status, task: [] }` on the object if it doesn't exist yet, then push to the task array:

```js
const items = [
    {status:'all',task:'AA'},
    {status:'all',task:'BB'},
    {status:'working',task:'XX'},
    {status:'working',task:'YY'},
    {status:'complete',task:'ZZ'},
];

const itemsByStatus = {};
for (const { status, task } of items) {
  itemsByStatus[status] ??= { status, task: [] };
  itemsByStatus[status].task.push(task);
}
console.log(Object.values(itemsByStatus));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it.
Thank kind of code is magic for me. 
Can I ask some for your code?

itemsByStatus[status] ??= { status, task: [] };

I never seen "??" . What meaning in your code?

Comment: Nullish assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment Here, equivalent to `if (!itemsByStatus[status]) itemsByStatus[status] =` which is a lot more verbose

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
So if I rewrite use if statement, like below?

for (const { status, task } of items) {
  if (!itemsByStatus[status]) {
    itemsByStatus[status] = { status, task: [] };
    itemsByStatus[status].task.push(task);
  }
  console.log(Object.values(itemsByStatus));
}

Comment: Yes, you can do that instead, it'll have the same result in the end